# Python script couldnt detect mismatch when $instance deleted in only one of the value nvp_add in double if else input statement

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, compare

This is continuation question from *stackoverflow* question below:
How do I filter nested cases to be filter out python
[How to compare the attributes start with $ in 2 functions and display match or mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325605/how-to-compare-the-attributes-start-with-in-2-functions-and-display-match-or-m/18325700#18325700)

When i delete one of the `$apsChanConfigNumber` from `nvp_add` in first block of if, the compare python script from link above couldn't detect the mismatch, there are 2 `nvp_add` function under this case. How to resolve the issue help!!!

Input file ASCII plain text contain text below:

---

```
        if(exists($snmpTrapEnterprise))
        {
            if(match($OPTION_EnableDetails, "1") or 
     match($OPTION_EnableDetails_juniper, "1")) {
                   details($snmpTrapEnterprise,$apsChanStatusSwitchovers,$apsChanStatusCurrent,$apsChanConfigGroupName,$apsChanConfigNumber)

            }
            @ExtendedAttr = nvp_add(@ExtendedAttr, "snmpTrapEnterprise", $snmpTrapEnterprise, "apsChanStatusSwitchovers", $apsChanStatusSwitchovers, "apsChanStatusCurrent", $apsChanStatusCurrent,
                 "apsChanConfigGroupName", , "apsChanConfigNumber",)
        }
        else
        {
            if(match($OPTION_EnableDetails, "1") or 
  match($OPTION_EnableDetails_juniper, "1")) {



details($apsChanStatusSwitchovers,$apsChanStatusCurrent,$apsChanConfigGroupName,$apsChanConfigNumber)
                }
                @ExtendedAttr = nvp_add(@ExtendedAttr, "apsChanStatusSwitchovers", 
      $apsChanStatusSwitchovers, "apsChanStatusCurrent", $apsChanStatusCurrent, 
      "apsChanConfigGroupName", $apsChanConfigGroupName,
                     "apsChanConfigNumber", $apsChanConfigNumber)
            }
```

Comment: Again, this isn't Python. What the heck are you doing?

Comment: Yes this is input file ascii contain perl, dont get confuse..see python script in How to compare the attributes start with $ in 2 functions and display match or mismatch.

Comment: The person who answered your other question was exceptionally nice to take the time to actually understand what you're asking and to code things up for you. You shouldn't always expect things to work out that way when you put zero effort into your question. Start by reviewing http://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since ive started, ill finish :P

```
import re
import sys
from collections import Counter

#sys.stdout = open("result.txt", 'w+')


def intersect(list1, list2):
  for o in list1:
    if o in list2:
      list1.remove(o)
      list2.remove(o)
  return list1, list2

def read(in_file):
  cases = []
  caselines_index = []
  readlines = []
  readlines_num = []
  with open(in_file, 'r') as file:
    readfile = file.read().strip()
    for line in readfile.split('\n'):
      readlines_num.append(line.strip())
    regex = re.compile("switch\(\$\d\).+?\}", re.DOTALL)
    readfile = re.sub(regex, ' ', readfile)
    for line in readfile.split('\n'):
      readlines.append(line.strip())
    for line in readlines:
      case_search = re.search("case\s\".+?\"\:\s", line)
      if case_search:
        caselines_index.append(readlines.index(line))
    #print caselines_index
    caselines_index_iter = iter(caselines_index)
    try:
      int_line_index = int(next(caselines_index_iter))
    except:
      print "No cases found"
    try:
      int_next_index = int(next(caselines_index_iter))
    except:
      int_next_index = len(readlines) - 1
    while True:
      try:
        case_text = ' '.join(readlines[int_line_index:int_next_index]).strip()
        match1 = re.search("nvp_add", case_text)
        match2 = re.search("details", case_text)
        if match1 or match2:
          case = [readlines[int_line_index].strip(), readlines_num.index(readlines[int_line_index]) + 1, case_text]
          cases.append(case)
        int_line_index = int_next_index
        int_next_index = int(next(caselines_index_iter))
      except StopIteration:
        case_text = ' '.join(readlines[int_line_index:len(readlines) - 1]).strip()
        case = [readlines[int_line_index].strip(), readlines_num.index(readlines[int_line_index]), case_text]
        cases.append(case)
        break
  return cases

def work(cases):
  MATCH = 1
  for case_list in cases:
    details = []
    nvp_add = []
    caseline = case_list[0].strip()
    nvp = re.findall("details\(.+?\)", case_list[2].strip())

    for item in nvp:
      result_list = re.findall("(\$.+?)[\,\)]", item)

      for result in result_list:
        if "$*" not in result:
          details.append(result)

    nvp = re.findall("nvp_add\(.+?\)", case_list[2].strip())

    for item in nvp:
      result_list = re.findall("(\$.+?)[\,\)]", item)

      for result in result_list:
        if "$*" not in result:
          nvp_add.append(result)


    nvp_add_c = Counter(nvp_add)
    details_c = Counter(details)
    missing_from_details = list((nvp_add_c - details_c).elements())
    missing_from_nvp_add = list((details_c - nvp_add_c).elements())
    if missing_from_nvp_add or missing_from_details:
      MATCH = 0
      print caseline + "   LINE - " + str(case_list[1] + 1)
      for mismatch in missing_from_details:
        print "Missing from details:"
        print mismatch
      for mismatch in missing_from_nvp_add:
        print "Missing from nvp_add:"
        print mismatch
      print "\n"
  if MATCH == 1:
    print "MATCH"
  else:
    print "MISMATCHES"


def main():
  in_file = "target1.txt"
  cases = read(in_file)
  work(cases)


if __name__=="__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: At least there is one intelligent person to resolve my issue !

Comment: haha you shouldnt say that, there are lots of intelligent people on SO, I just had the time to help you :) , next time, try coding a bit yourself ;)